# VirtualBox natnetwork start failed

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I use VirtualBox 5.0.16_Ubuntu, Ubuntu 16.04. When I added a new NAT network and try to start natnetwork service, I got some error:

`~$ VBoxManage natnetwork add --netname openstack --network "192.168.15.0/24" --enable --dhcp off
~$ VBoxManage natnetwork start --netname openstack
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) - Operation failed (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "Start(Bstr("whatever").raw())" at line 408 of file VBoxManageNATNetwork.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Failed to start network`

What can I do with it?

Comment: Problem is fixed in VirtualBOX 5.1.